# Will data binding unregister listeners from a ViewModel implementing Observable?

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

I have some more complex logic for data provided by my `ViewModel` to the UI, so simply exposing the data via `LiveData` won't do the job for me. Now I've seen in the Android [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/architecture#observable-viewmodel) that I can implement `Observable` on my `ViewModel` to get the fine-grained control I need.

However in the documentation it also says:

> There are situations where you might prefer to use a ViewModel
>   component that implements the Observable interface over using LiveData
>   objects, even if **you lose the lifecycle management capabilities of
>   LiveData**.

How intelligent is the built-in Android data binding? Will it automatically unregister it's listeners when necessary (e.g. on configuration changes where the View is destroyey) so that I don't have to care about the lost lifecycle capabilities? Or do I have to watch the Lifecycle of the View and unregister it's listeners? (=do manually what LiveData normally does for me).

Comment: `I have some more complex logic for data provided by my ViewModel to the UI, so simply exposing the data via LiveData won't do the job for me.` maybe it is possible, but we can't know without knowing the exact problem.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I want to create an exposed dropdown (the new material components "spinner") which besides predefined items also offers a value "custom value". the value of the exposed dropdown shall be data bound, however the ViewModel property shall not be updated when "custom value" (which will trigger a dialog to be shown) is selected. also no updates shall be triggered when the dialog is aborted and the selection "custom value" goes back to the old value (google contacts app field label -> custom is basically the behaviour I want to reproduce)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How intelligent is the built-in Android data binding? Will it automatically unregister it's listeners when necessary (e.g. on configuration changes where the View is destroyey) so that I don't have to care about the lost lifecycle capabilities? Or do I have to watch the Lifecycle of the View and unregister it's listeners? (=do manually what LiveData normally does for me).

So I did some tests. I implemented `androidx.databinding.Observable` on my `ViewModel` and did a configuration change with the following log calls:

```
override fun removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(
    callback: androidx.databinding.Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
    Log.d("APP:EVENTS", "removeOnPropertyChangedCallback " + callback.toString())
}

override fun addOnPropertyChangedCallback(
    callback: androidx.databinding.Observable.OnPropertyChangedCallback?) {
    Log.d("APP:EVENTS", "addOnPropertyChangedCallback " + callback.toString())
}
```

I saw that `addOnPropertyChangedCallback` was invoked for each time my viewmodel was referenced in a layout binding expression. And not once did I see `removeOnPropertyChangedCallback` invoked. My initial conclusion is that AndroidX databinding is dumb and does not automagically remove the listener.
<sup>**FYI:** the callback type was ViewDataBinding.WeakPropertyListener</sup>

However, I took a peek at [`ViewDataBinding.java` source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/data-binding/+/c9a5d6f140f732ca0ff279a4b1ee315072e1c422/library/src/main/java/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding.java) and found that it is using [Weak References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) to add the listener.

So what this implies, is that upon a configuration change, Android OS should be able to garbage collect your Activity/Fragment because the viewmodel does not have a strong reference.

**My advice: Don't add the boilerplate to unregister the listeners. Android will not leak references to your activities and fragments on configuration changes**.

Now, if you choose not to use `LiveData`, consider making your viewmodel implement `LifecycleObserver` so that you can re-emit the most recent value when your Activity/Fragment goes into the active state. This is the key behavior you lose by not using `LiveData`. Otherwise, you can emit notifications by using the `PropertyChangeRegistry.notifyCallbacks()` as mentioned in the documentation you shared at some other time. Unfortunately, I think this can only be used to notify for *all* properties.

Another thing... while I've not verified the behavior the source code seems to indicate that weak references are used for `ObservableField`, `ObservableList`, `ObservableMap`, etc.

`LiveData` is different for a couple of reasons:

1. [The documentation for `LiveData.observe`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/LiveData#observe(androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner,%20androidx.lifecycle.Observer<?%20super%20T>)) says that a strong reference is held to both the observer AND the lifecycle owner until the lifecycle owner is destroyed.
2. `LiveData` emits differently than `ObservableField`. `LiveData` will emit whenever `setValue` or `postValue` are called without regard to if the value actually changes. This is not true for `ObservableField`. For this reason, `LiveData` can be used to send a somewhat "pseudo-event" by setting the same value more than once. An example of where this can be useful can be found on the [Conditional Navigation page](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#user_login) where multiple login failures would trigger multiple snackbars.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. `ViewModel` will not unregister `Observable` subscription automatically. You can do it manually though. It is pretty easy.

- Firstly you create `CompositeDisposable`

```
    protected var disposables = CompositeDisposable()
```

- Secondly, create your `Observable`(it may be some request or UI event listener) subscribe to it and assign its result to `CompositeDisposable`

```
    disposables.add(
        someObservable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ data ->
                // update UI or some ObservableFields for view/databinding
            }, { exception ->
                // handle errors here
            })
    )
```

- The last thing you should do is to override `ViewModel`'s method `onCleared()` like this:

```
    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        disposables.clear()
    }
```

This way all subscription added to your `CompositeDisposable` will be cleared automatically

**Edit**

I showed only the example. You may add triggers in onConfigurationChanged or onCreate or onResume to clear subscriptions as well - but it is dependent on specific usecases of an app. I gave just a general one.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why is it a `var` and not a `val`?

Comment: first of all, thanks. Actually it's not about if the `ViewModel` unregisters the subscription, but if the Data Binding glueing the `ViewModel` and UI will unregister it. I also think that your solutions clears the disposables too late. What about configuration changes? The view will be destroyed, new observers will be added. However you clear the observers only when the `ViewModel` is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

DataBinding would not do the unregistering for you. Its simply help bind your layout file and the ViewModel. It is the viewModel that will protect you from device's configuration change. You still need to apply onSavedViewState() in your base activity or fragment as viewModel does not cover that. As per unregistering, LiveData does that.

As @Pavio already taught you how to create Observable, that is RxJava working. I would suggest using kotlin's coroutines and viewModel with LiveData to get the best out of your situation. Rx has a learning curve to it, although it does offer hundred of operators for all sorts of operations. If you really want to learn the kotlin way, look into kotlin flows and channels.

If i was in your place, I would solve my problem with ViewModels, LiveData and Coroutines.